# Obtaining a list of 2x2 matrices from a large matrix in Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix, iteration

I have been working on a coding challenge for some time just for fun, the problem is this:
**Given a rectangular matrix containing only digits, calculate the number of different 2 × 2 squares in it.**

The 2x2 matrices may be overlapping. Inputs can be up to 100 x 100 matrices and will be rectangular but not necessarily square. I was able to solve this problem using nested loops, the problem is that it is too slow for inputs that are large matrices and it exceeds the time limit (4000ms) of the coding challenge. This is how I initially solved it.

```
def differentSquares(matrix)
    i = 0
    squares = []
    while i < matrix.length - 1 
        j = 0
        while j < matrix[i].length - 1 
            current = [matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]]
            squares << current if !squares.include?(current)
            j += 1 
        end 
        i += 1 
    end 
    squares.length 
end
```

I have considered somehow using a hash because they are much faster to iterate through than an array, but I can't figure out how to do that. Can anyone help me find an implementation that is faster than a nested loop?

Examples of input and expected output:

```
input:   
[[2,5,3,4,3,1,3,2],   
 [4,5,4,1,2,4,1,3],   
 [1,1,2,1,4,1,1,5],   
 [1,3,4,2,3,4,2,4],   
 [1,5,5,2,1,3,1,1],   
 [1,2,3,3,5,1,2,4],   
 [3,1,4,4,4,1,5,5],   
 [5,1,3,3,1,5,3,5],   
 [5,4,4,3,5,4,4,4]] 

expected output: 54  

another input:   
[[1,2,1],   
 [2,2,2],   
 [2,2,2],   
 [1,2,3],   
 [2,2,1]]

expected output: 6
```

Comment: Some very-minor speedup could come from: using a Set for `squares`. And then just add 'current' without checking (Set will ensure uniqueness).
Also you can make sure you only call 'length' just once (as the matrix is rectangular). But that will not cut a lot of time, i guess. So you need to find a better algorithm...

Comment: Wow! i have never heard of Set before, but I tried it and it worked! Thanks Pascal, I really appreciate it. I will be looking more into the Set data structure now, thanks for introducing me to it.

Comment: Could you give an example input and output?

Comment: @Stefan I updated the question to include examples.

Comment: I think your description of the problem could use some improvement, since going by your description alone, I would have expected the result of the second example to be 4, not 6.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I mentioned clearly in the description that the matrices can in fact be overlapping.

Comment: Nevermind, I can't count. There's 8 squares and 2 duplicates. I counted 6 squares and 2 duplicates and then thought the answer should be 4.

Comment: Oh, my comment should have read: very-minor-speedup for extracting the calls to `length`, not for using a `Set` where I'd expect a bigger speedup as the lookup for duplicates is much faster (see Jörgs comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a collection of the proposed solutions including a benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark/ips'
require 'set'
require 'matrix'

def generate(x, y, max)
  matrix = []
  x.times do
    row = []
    y.times do
      row << rand(max)
    end
    matrix << row
  end
  matrix
end

def original(matrix)
    i = 0
    squares = []
    while i < matrix.length - 1
        j = 0
        while j < matrix[i].length - 1
            current = [matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]]
            squares << current if !squares.include?(current)
            j += 1
        end
        i += 1
    end
    squares.length
end

def with_set(matrix)
  i = 0
  squares = Set.new
  while i < matrix.length - 1
    j = 0
    while j < matrix[i].length - 1
      squares << [matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]]
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  squares.length
end

def with_set_and_length(matrix)
  i = 0
  squares = Set.new
  a = matrix.length - 1
  b = matrix.first.length - 1
  while i < a
    j = 0
    while j < b
      squares << [matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]]
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  squares.length
end

def foo(matrix)
  matrix.each_cons(2) do |row|
    row.each_cons(2) do |col|

    end
  end
end

def with_each_cons(m)
  m.each_cons(2).flat_map { |a, b| a.each_cons(2).zip(b.each_cons(2)) }.uniq.count
end

def with_each_cons_rearanged(m)
  m.map { |a| a.each_cons(2).to_a }.each_cons(2).flat_map { |a, b| a.zip(b) }.uniq.count
end

def with_matrix(m)
  (m.row_count-1).times.flat_map do |i|
    (m.column_count-1).times.map { |j| m.minor(i,2,j,2) }
  end.uniq.size
end


def with_matrix_and_set(m)
  set = Set.new
  (m.row_count-1).times do |i|
    (m.column_count-1).times do |j|
      set << m.minor(i, 2, j, 2)
    end
  end
  set.size
end

array_matrix = generate(100, 100, 20)
real_matrix = m = Matrix[*array_matrix]

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.compare!
  x.report('original') do
    original(array_matrix)
  end
  x.report('with_set') do
    with_set(array_matrix)
  end
  x.report('with_set_and_length') do
    with_set_and_length(array_matrix)
  end
  x.report('with_each_cons') do
    with_each_cons(array_matrix)
  end
  x.report('with_each_cons_rearanged') do
    with_each_cons_rearanged(array_matrix)
  end
  x.report('with_matrix') do
    with_matrix(real_matrix)
  end
  x.report('with_matrix_and_set') do
    with_matrix_and_set(real_matrix)
  end
end
```

Results:

```
Comparison:
 with_set_and_length:       52.7 i/s
            with_set:       52.0 i/s - 1.01x slower
with_each_cons_rearanged:       31.4 i/s - 1.68x slower
 with_matrix_and_set:       21.0 i/s - 2.52x slower
      with_each_cons:       18.7 i/s - 2.82x slower
         with_matrix:       17.5 i/s - 3.01x slower
            original:        0.1 i/s - 605.89x slower
```

Comment: I'd be grateful if you could add my method to your benchmark.

Comment: Updated with solution by @CarySwoveland which uses `Matrix` (as well as a variant that uses `Matrix` + `Set`). @CarySwoveland: i moved creation of the 'Matrix' out of the benchmark but it is still slower than the array one. I assume there is more overhead as 'Matrix' uses 'Array' internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is both, short and fast:

```
def different_squares(m)
  m.each_cons(2).flat_map { |a, b| a.each_cons(2).zip(b.each_cons(2)) }.uniq.count
end
```

It takes advantage of [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) and [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

Rearranging the methods makes it faster:

```
def different_squares(m)
  m.map { |a| a.each_cons(2).to_a }.each_cons(2).flat_map { |a, b| a.zip(b) }.uniq.count
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like this, too. I think you can't do better than O(n^2), or more precisely O(n*m), but I would be happy to be proven wrong. (Or, correct.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag probably not, maybe you can approach the whole problem differently.

Comment: @Stefan oh wow this is impressive. thanks for your response. i will definitely be studying this example to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Pascal Betz suggestion of using a Set:

```
require 'set'

def differentSquares(matrix)
    i = 0
    squares = Set.new 
    while i < matrix.length - 1 
        j = 0
        while j < matrix[i].length - 1 
            current = [matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]]
            squares.add(current)
            j += 1 
        end 
        i += 1 
    end 
    squares.length 
end
```

Although as Pascal mentioned, the algorithm is still not very good and I would love some suggestions of a better algorithm.

Comment: Your original algorithm was O(n^4), or more precisely O((n * m)^2), this one is O(n^2), or more precisely O(n * m). I would be interested to see whether it is possible to do better, but I can't think of something clever right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'matrix'

def nbr_uniq_2x2_submatrices(arr)
  m = Matrix[*arr]
  (m.row_count-1).times.flat_map do |i|
    (m.column_count-1).times.map { |j| m.minor(i,2,j,2) }
  end.uniq.size
end

arr = [[2,5,3,4,3,1,3,2],
       [4,5,4,1,2,4,1,3],
       [1,1,2,1,4,1,1,5],
       [1,3,4,2,3,4,2,4],
       [1,5,5,2,1,3,1,1],
       [1,2,3,3,5,1,2,4],
       [3,1,4,4,4,1,5,5],
       [5,1,3,3,1,5,3,5],
       [5,4,4,3,5,4,4,4]]

nbr_uniq_2x2_submatrices(arr)
  #=> 54
```

Class and instance methods for the class `Matrix` are documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html).